# Unexpected cold Observable behavior

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I thought I understood the difference between cold and hot Observable, but apparently something escapes me. This code works as expected:

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.interval(2000);

var A = obs.subscribe(function(value) { console.log('A', value) });
var B = obs.subscribe(function(value) { console.log('B', value) });
```

With this, I get the following result:

```
A 0
B 0
A 1
B 1
...
```

But when I add a `flatMap` to retrieve a remote JSONP resource:

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.interval(2000).flatMap(function() {
  return Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest({ url: URL });
})
.map(function(value) { return value.prop; });

var A = obs.subscribe(function(value) { console.log('A', value) });
var B = obs.subscribe(function(value) { console.log('B', value) });
```

I only receive `A` logs:

```
A prop
A prop
A prop
...
```

If turn the Observable into a hot one using `publish().refCount()`, it works as I would expect, which is that both subscribers receive the same values.

Now, I understand that by the Observer being cold, I shouldn't expect to receive the same values at the same time, but I would expect that both `A` and `B` observers receive values, not only `A`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: indeed that should work.  Put a `console.log` statement before the `jsonpRequest` line.  Also add an onError and onComplete handlers to your `subscribe` calls with more log statements.  Perhaps the `B` subscription is failing for some weird reason when it tries to issue a duplicate jsonp request?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. The `console.log` before the `jsonpRequest` line gets called twice, though. Also, if I put `B` inside a `setTimeout` it works as expected. /cc @Brandon

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in RxJs-DOM and you should open an issue.  <s>I believe you can work around the bug by passing the URL as a string literal instead of an object:</s>

`return Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest(URL);`

**Edit**: Re-reading the source, I don't think that work-around will work.  I think you must use `defer` to work-around the bug:

```
return Rx.Observable.defer(function () { return Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest({ url: URL }); });
```